# How to get return value in my html file calling async javascript function in another file?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await, ethereum

I have my index.html file with a simple form

Update

```
<form onSubmit=" App.estraiVincitore().then(value => { alert (value)}); return false;">
    <input type="submit" value="Get Winner">
    <input type="text" name="winner">    
 </form>
```

I have a App.js file with an async function that works properly getting an event transaction.

```
estraiVincitore: async() => {
  await App.vincitoreDelContest.estrazioneVincitore().then(function (value) {
      console.log(value.logs[0].args.username);
      return value.logs[0].args.username;   //returned value to show in my index.html
       
  });
```

How can I get the returned valued from my JavaScript function and shows it in my index.html?
Properly I would like to show it in my text area.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FWIW, don't use `await` *and* `.then`. Just use `await`. As for showing the value, you would update an elements content, e.g. `document.getElementById("name").textContent = ...`.

Comment: @FelixKling doesn't work. App.vincitoreDelContest.estrazioneVincitore() is an async transaction to Ethereum blockchain and modifying doesn't print for example console.log(value.logs[0].args.username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the returned valued from my JavaScript function and shows it in my index.html?

By using the promise that `estraiVincitore` returns in JavaScript code in the `index.html` file. An `async` function returns a promise; **later**, that promise is settled (fulfilled with a value, or rejected with a "reason" [error]).

So for instance:

```js
App.estraiVincitore()
.then(value => {
    document.querySelector("selector-for-your-text-area").value = value;
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report the error...
});
```

---

Re [Felix's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957625/how-to-get-return-value-in-my-html-file-calling-async-javascript-function-in-ano/62957701#comment111333710_62957625), the purpose of `async`/`await` is to make it possible to use promises with simple logical flow constructs rather than callbacks. So:

```js
estraiVincitore: async() => {
  const value = await App.vincitoreDelContest.estrazioneVincitore();
  console.log(value.logs[0].args.username);
  return value.logs[0].args.username;
}
```

Which is (basically) equivalent to this non-`async` function:

```js
estraiVincitore: () => {
  return App.vincitoreDelContest.estrazioneVincitore().then(value => {
      console.log(value.logs[0].args.username);
      return value.logs[0].args.username;
  });
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, the alert in HTML form get "undefined". 
Modifying estraiVinciotre function in both way doesn't work. My App.vincitoreDelContest.estrazioneVincitore() is an async transaction to ethereum blockchain

Comment: @alfo888_ibg - That's because your `async` function doesn't **return** the result of calling `then`, so its promise is fulfilled with `undefined`. If you update it to match either of the examples in the answer, it will work correctly.